# ajax how to update current page at the same time as the target page without refresh

Tags: ajax

first time posting here so i am sorry if im not posting the question in the right way

I am building social media site and iam having accept,reject buttons and using ajax to update database with the user click,  everything works but the problem that im numbering these accept and reject buttons beginning  from 0, the problem happens if i click accept in the middle so the order changes and the two pages fail to communicate right so the problem will be solved if i can update the current page but i dont want to refresh the page

so is there a soultion to my problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: show some code, you can use Jquery

Comment: Please edit the question to improve formatting and include sample code that shows what you've tried already.

Comment: ok i have added the code , please take a look, the main problem is that mysql fetcharray loop update in the second page but not in the first

Answer (score 0):

initialization inside looping will always reset the value to 0.  $i =0 initialization should come outside of while loop.

```
<?php
 $i=0;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {

     echo"<button value='accept' class = 'btn btn-success $i'>accept</button>";
     echo"<button value='reject' class = 'btn btn-success $i'>reject</button>";
     $i=$i+1;
 }
```

?>

Comment: thanks for trying to help but actually i copied it wrong here, i have it right in my code, the problem is the loop in directed ajax code is uodated while the loop in the main page is only done once

Comment: post the full code of test.php which is an ajax call to update. And the provide screen shot of " if i click accept in the middle so the order changes "

Comment: i solved the problem by writing sql to find row by its index in the table in the database thanks for trying to help though